# Combining 2 problems in NP into one

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, np, decision-problem, oracle-machines

Say I have a deterministic turing machine which solves decision problem S with oracle access to both problems B, C that are in $NP$. 
Can S be solved with oracle access to only **one** problem in $NP$?

That is, can B and C somehow be combined into one problem in $NP$ (thus showing S is in $P^{NP}$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do it. The first is to take a disjoint sum of $B$ and $C$, which can be done in many ways, for example
$$
\{0x : x \in B\} \cup \{1y : y \in C\}.
$$
The second is to use an NP-complete language $L$ as an oracle. Since any problem in NP reduces to $L$ in polynomial time, you can simulate a $B$-oracle using an $L$-oracle.

Comment: Thank you very much Yuval!

Comment: Another downvoter not bothering to leave a comment...